# WPF Dependency guide

Tags: c#, wpf

I’m trying to learn some WPF tricks and I’m stuck on WPF-Dependency.
Can anybody explain what is it and it’s use. Any websites with the explanation of using it.

Comment: What Dependencies? Dependency properties?

Comment: Dependency properties are one of the most useful features of WPF. Go ahead and practice WPF and I am sure you will love it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is Dependency**

Dependency means an object depending upon another object.

An object O1 depends upon another object O2 when O1 is using O2's property to do some changes in its own(O1) property.

**Why we need it**

To achieve these changes, some notification logic is needed of-course. Before WPF or similar technology, we were doing it using event handlers.

Now, with WPF and similar technologies, we tell the *underlying framework* to do this for us. We tell *underlying framework* what we want ( using some syntax ) without bothering how ? And *underlying framework* does this for us.

**Provisions provided by WPF**

1. Binding using code/xaml.
2. DependencyProperty
3. Triggers
4. INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Learn about these, and slowly you will get the hold of it.

Comment: Oo, thx. Hmm, loks like it is rly powerful